# Copying boundary values between groups in glsl compute shaders

Tags: glsl, gpu, gpgpu, vulkan, compute-shader

So a lot of questions like this have been asked, but in my situation, *I actually need to share the data*.

Here's my situation.  I've got a program that aims to fill a 3D texture with values  starting from the top working its way down.  The program fills a sort of waterfall model.

A function which takes the value associated with the cell in a 3D texture, and its position relative to the current cell, ie `f(x, position)` and produces a new value added to the current cell.  You can kind of think of it like a flood fill of sorts

[image]

Now if I only needed the adjacent values, I could just use ghost points, the issue is that a single value spreads from its current location outwards, so adjacent values will be updated outside of what ever current block I'm operating in.

Now I don't need to transfer the entire block of data from adjacent blocks, I just need, at each step, the values of adjacent blocks surrounding the current grid. I'll still be using ghost points, but I'll need to transfer the "new" values in to use them.

[image]

My issue is that it appears that every one says "use another compute shader invocation" to get around this.  That isn't acceptable, there isn't enough work to justify the kernel startup cost.

The only options I see are:

- use atomic ints to communicate across groups to let groups know they can use the value in some global memory which corresponds to these boundary data items
- sextuple the run-time by copying values of adjacent cells into a separate buffer, then running the entire process over again to account for the new adjacent values for each side (there are 6 in a cube).
- use only one group invocation for the entire thing. There may be enough other things that the GPU is doing to warrant this
- using multiple compute shader invocations for each "layer" of the 3D texture, which would require dumping the values to global memory, then reading them back in for every layer, effectively doubling the cost of global memory reads and invoking kernel overhead as each kernel needs to be launched in order. If I could keep the same memory in shared memory between kernel invocations and not have to re-read it back in, this would mitigate the double latency issue.

Is there really no other way to copy boundaries in compute shaders?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really no other way to copy boundaries in compute shaders?

In the general case, no.

There is no guarantee when the adjacent boundary group will be executed, so how do you copy what might not exist yet?

You might be able to block and wait, but that's inefficient (GPUs will just busy wait) and might actually live-lock because all the running groups are blocked waiting and new ones can't start (because the blocked ones are using all of the thread capacity of the shader core).

If I understand your algorithm right, what's worse is that you have a circular dependency (the boundary propagates bi-directionally both to and from adjacent blocks), so unless you can spawn your entire problem space simultaneously then it's guaranteed to live-lock.

Comment: I can spawn the entire problem space simultaneously... and there wouldn't be livelock. assuming you use the atomic communication method, you would just make sure that thread A had output for its current step, before thread B could continue to the next step, but both can continue on their current steps with out input from each other.  For your purposes, just think of this as a flood fill, but with multiple flood points potentially mixing together.  The program still works if you launch it as separate kernels for each iteration as long as there is a memory dependency from the previous step.